# How to schedule an export from a BigQuery table to Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have successfully scheduled my query in BigQuery, and the result is saved as a table in my dataset. I see a lot of information about scheduling data transfer **in** to BigQuery or Cloud Storage, but I haven't found anything regarding scheduling an export **from** a BigQuery table to Cloud Storage yet.

Is it possible to schedule an export of a BigQuery table to Cloud Storage so that I can further schedule having it SFTP-ed to me via Google BigQuery Data Transfer Services?

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a managed service for scheduling BigQuery table exports, but one viable approach is to use **[Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)** in conjunction with **[Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/)**.

The Cloud Function would contain the necessary code to export to Cloud Storage from the BigQuery table. There are multiple programming languages to choose from for that, such as **Python**, **Node.JS**, and **Go**.

Cloud Scheduler would send an **HTTP** call periodically in a **cron** format to the Cloud Function which would in turn, get triggered and run the export programmatically.

As an **example** and more specifically, you can follow these steps:

1. [**Create a Cloud Function** using Python with an **HTTP** trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console#create_a_function). To interact with BigQuery from within the code you need to use the BigQuery [**client library**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries). Import it with `from google.cloud import bigquery`. Then, you can use the following code in **main.py** to create an export job from BigQuery to Cloud Storage:

   ```
       # Imports the BigQuery client library
       from google.cloud import bigquery

       def hello_world(request):
           # Replace these values according to your project
           project_name = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID" 
           bucket_name = "YOUR_BUCKET" 
           dataset_name = "YOUR_DATASET" 
           table_name = "YOUR_TABLE" 
           destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "bq_export.csv.gz")

           bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_name)

           dataset = bq_client.dataset(dataset_name, project=project_name)
           table_to_export = dataset.table(table_name)

           job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
           job_config.compression = bigquery.Compression.GZIP

           extract_job = bq_client.extract_table(
               table_to_export,
               destination_uri,
               # Location must match that of the source table.
               location="US",
               job_config=job_config,
           )  
           return "Job with ID {} started exporting data from {}.{} to {}".format(extract_job.job_id, dataset_name, table_name, destination_uri)
   ```

   Specify the client library dependency in the **requirements.txt** file
   by adding this line:

   ```
   google-cloud-bigquery
   ```
2. [**Create a Cloud Scheduler job**](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#creating_jobs). Set the *Frequency* you wish for
   the job to be executed with. For instance, setting it to `0 1 * * 0`
   would run the job once a week at 1 AM every Sunday morning. The
   [crontab tool](https://crontab.guru/) is pretty useful when it comes to experimenting
   with cron scheduling.

   Choose **HTTP** as the *Target*, set the *URL* as the Cloud
   Function's URL (it can be found by selecting the Cloud Function and
   navigating to the Trigger tab), and as HTTP method choose `GET`.

   Once created, and by pressing the *RUN NOW*  button, you can test how the export
   behaves. However, before doing so, make sure the [default App Engine service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/service-account) has at least the Cloud IAM [`roles/storage.objectCreator`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) role, or otherwise the operation might fail with a permission error. The default App Engine service account has a form of `YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`.

   If you wish to execute exports on different tables,
   datasets and buckets for each execution, but essentially employing the same Cloud Function, you can use the HTTP `POST` method 
   instead, and configure a *Body* containing said parameters as data, which
   would be passed on to the Cloud Function - although, that would imply doing
   some small changes in its code.

Lastly, when the job is created, you can use the Cloud Function's returned `job ID` and the `bq` CLI to view the status of the export job with `bq show -j <job_id>`.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this was in GA when this question was asked, but at least now there is an option to run an export to Cloud Storage via a regular SQL query. See the SQL tab in [Exporting table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data).

Example:

```
EXPORT DATA
  OPTIONS (
    uri = 'gs://bucket/folder/*.csv',
    format = 'CSV',
    overwrite = true,
    header = true,
    field_delimiter = ';')
AS (
  SELECT field1, field2
  FROM mydataset.table1
  ORDER BY field1
);
```

This could as well be trivially setup via a Scheduled Query if you need a periodic export. And, of course, you need to make sure the user or service account running this has permissions to read the source datasets and tables and to write to the destination bucket.

Hopefully this is useful for other peeps visiting this question if not for OP :)

Comment: works like a charm, much simpler than maxim's solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have an alternative to the second part of the Maxim answer. The code for extracting the table and store it into Cloud Storage should work.

But, when you schedule a query, you can also [define a PubSub topic where the BigQuery scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-run-notifications) will post a message when the job is over. Thereby, the scheduler set up, as described by Maxim is optional and you can simply [plug the function to the PubSub notification.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub)

Before performing the extraction, don't forget to check the [error status of the pubsub notification](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs.runs#TransferRun). You have also a lot of information about the scheduled query; useful is you want to perform more checks or if you want to generalize the function.

So, another point about the SFTP transfert. I [open sourced a projet for querying BigQuery, build a CSV file and transfert this file to FTP server](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/bqToFtp) (sFTP and FTPs aren't supported, because my previous company only used FTP protocol!). If your file is smaller than 1.5Gb, I can update my project for adding the SFTP support is you want to use this. Let me know

Comment: Guillaume, it would be really helpful if you can share that code