# Scheduling queries: Is there a way to bypass the minimum 15min interval?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm planning to run a DML query every 5 mins, but when setting it via UI prompts "Frequency limit exceeded. The required min_schedule_interval is [15m]". I've also tried to do it using the bq command-line tool via Cloud Shell Terminal with the same result. Is there a way to bypass this by other means?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest allowed period is 15 minutes for BigQuery scheduled queries as is depicted in [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query). As workarounds you could try the following:

- Use [Cloud Functions and Cloud Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687796) to try to run your query every 5 minutes.
- Create at least 3 scheduled queries and run them in an interval of 15 minutes (or according to the number of scheduled queries multiplied by 5 minutes). For example, query 1 runs at 10:00 hrs., query 2 runs at 10:05 hrs. and query 3 runs at 10:10 hrs. and then the query 1 runs at 10:15 hrs. again and query 2 runs at 10:20 hrs. again and so on.

Comment: I didn't even think about the first and simplest solution Noe...that would definitely do it :) thanks so much for your support!

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solved your problem. Even if you don't have the reputation to vote it up, that green checkmark is a signal that others should try this answer in the future.