# Could function failed to build with error I do not understand

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a cloud function to trigger an export from big query table to google cloud stoarge.
I read the link below and did the same thing as mentioned.

[How to schedule an export from a BigQuery table to Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687796/how-to-schedule-an-export-from-a-bigquery-table-to-cloud-storage)

Please see below what I have provided in my main.py

```
# Imports the BigQuery client library
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    def extract_data(request):
        # Replace these values according to your project
        project_name = "whr-asia-datalake-nonprod" 
        bucket_name = "whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/" 
        dataset_name = "WHR_DATALAKE" 
        table_name = "CONSUMER_EXTRACT" 
        destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name,"Consumer_master.csv")

        bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_name)

        dataset = bq_client.dataset(dataset_name, project=project_name)
        table_to_export = dataset.table(table_name)

        job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
        
        extract_job = bq_client.extract_table(
            table_to_export,
            destination_uri,
            # Location must match that of the source table.
            location="asia-south1",
            job_config=job_config,
        )  
        return "Job with ID {} started exporting data from {}.{} to {}".format(extract_job.job_id, dataset_name, table_name, destination_uri)
```

And in requirements.txt, I have provided as below

```
google-cloud-bigquery
```

My cloud function will get triggered from a pub sub topic which creates an event once the big query table that I need to extract data from is loaded.

However, the function is failed to deploy and I get an error as below which I am unable to understand.
Please can someone help me to fix this. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
2021-02-13T11:23:38.518815ZCloud FunctionsUpdateFunctionasia-south1:xxxx@xxxx.com {@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, methodName: google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction, resourceName: projects/whr-asia-datalake-nonprod/locations/asia-south1/functions/Consumer_Extract_Bigquery, serviceName: cloudfunctions.google…
{@type: type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog, authenticationInfo: {…}, methodName: google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction, resourceName: projects/whr-asia-datalake-nonprod/locations/asia-south1/functions/Consumer_Extract_Bigquery, serviceName: cloudfunctions.google…
```

I was able to fix this by adding below in main.py

```
# Imports the BigQuery client library
from google.cloud import bigquery
def extract_data(event, context):
 # Replace these values according to your project
    project_name = "whr-asia-datalake-nonprod"
    bucket_name = "whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/"
    dataset_name = "WHR_DATALAKE"
    table_name = "CONSUMER_EXTRACT"
    destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name,"Consumer_master.csv")
    bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_name)
    dataset = bq_client.dataset(dataset_name, project=project_name)
    table_to_export = dataset.table(table_name)
    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    extract_job = bq_client.extract_table(
    table_to_export,
    destination_uri,
    # Location must match that of the source table.
    location="asia-south1",
    job_config=job_config,
    )
    return "Job with ID {} started exporting data from {}.{} to {}".format(extract_job.job_id, dataset_name, table_name, destination_uri)
```

and adding below in requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-bigquery==1
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==1
```

Comment: Hi @Maxim, could you please help me here? Not able to fix this. Your inputs will help me as this is what I have done based on your inputs to other query. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thank you @Chris32 for editing it. I didnt realize I had provided the account details.

Comment: The error is with  def extract_data(request), its not an HTTP trigger but a pub sub topic. What shall I replace this with?

Comment: Hi @Maxim, I am trying to create pipe delimiter with a header in the file. I am now able to create the file but the requirement is to create pipe delimiter and with header.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally do this successfully. Please find below the code in cloud function that will be triggered through a pub sub event.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
def extract_data(event, context):
 # Replace these values according to your project
    project_name = "whr-asia-datalake-nonprod"
    bucket_name = "whr-asia-datalake-dev-standard/outbound/Adobe/"
    dataset_name = "WHR_DATALAKE"
    table_name = "C4C_CONSUMER_CURATED"
    destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name,"Consumer_master_test.txt")
    bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_name)
    dataset = bq_client.dataset(dataset_name, project=project_name)
    table_to_export = dataset.table(table_name)
    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    job_config.field_delimiter = "|"
    job_config.print_header = True

    extract_job = bq_client.extract_table(
    table_to_export,
    destination_uri,
    # Location must match that of the source table.
    location="asia-south1",
    job_config=job_config,
    )
    return "Job with ID {} started exporting data from {}.{} to {}".format(extract_job.job_id, dataset_name, table_name, destination_uri)
```

I was able to provide other attributes for bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig like pipe delimiter and header.

Thanks to @maxim. your post helped me a lot.